# Display flex horizontally centering issue

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid, display

I have an issue to center an element in my div.

I'm using **display flex**, **align-self** and **justify-self** to center it.

I think this is ok by this way, but I have an unknown element when I inspect from the web browser.

[image]

You can see on the right, there is an as striped element that I don't know where it come from.

Here is the parent element made with grid.

[image]

You can see the issue from the fiddle here

https://jsfiddle.net/Martin40/qtjphvga/3/

Here is my CSS

```
.customer_card{
    background: green;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 20% 80%;
    gap: 0px 10px;
    justify-content: center;
    justify-items: stretch;
    align-items: center;
}

.customer_card_logo {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    justify-self: center;
    text-align: center;
    background: grey;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.customer_card_logo > .material-icons-outlined {
    align-self: center;
    justify-self: center;
    font-size: 2rem;
    transition: all 0.4s;
}
.customer_card_logo:hover > .material-icons-outlined {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.customer_card_name {
    display: block;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.customer_card_addresse {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}
```

Here is my HTML

```
<head><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined|Material+Icons+Two+Tone|Material+Icons+Round|Material+Icons+Sharp" rel="stylesheet"></head>

<div class="customer_card">
<div class="customer_card_logo"><span class="material-icons-outlined"> autorenew </span></div>
<div class="customer_card_informations">
    <span class="customer_card_name">Company Name</span>
    <span class="customer_card_addresse">Adresse <br> ZIP CITY NAME</span>
</div>
```

Anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: Issue? what issue? You have a `gap` defined in the parent.

Comment: Thats not an element,its a gap/space that the browser higlights

Comment: it's not clear what your issue is - if it's the gap in the logo circle - it's because your circle is 50px and your icon is 32px - if you want to centre the icon, just add `align-items:center; justify-content:center;` to your logo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't talk about the gap of the grid but the stripped element in the flex

```
justify-content: center;
```

On the **customer_card_logo** saved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The "striped element" is just the grid gap you have defined on `.customer_card` here (doesn't cause the centering issue):

```css
gap: 0px 10px;
```

To center the icon, replace the width/height-based approach with using `padding` instead. This way, you don't have to worry about the size of the icon which could cause misalignments:

```css
.customer_card_logo {
    /* width: 50px; */
    /* height: 50px; */
    padding: 0.5rem;
}
```

Try the modified snippet below:

```css
.customer_card {
  background: green;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 80%;
  gap: 0px 10px;
  justify-content: center;
  justify-items: stretch;
  align-items: center;
}

.customer_card_logo {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  justify-self: center;
  text-align: center;
  background: grey;
  border-radius: 50%;
  #width: 50px;
  #height: 50px;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.customer_card_logo>.material-icons-outlined {
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}

.customer_card_logo:hover>.material-icons-outlined {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.customer_card_name {
  display: block;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.customer_card_addresse {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined|Material+Icons+Two+Tone|Material+Icons+Round|Material+Icons+Sharp" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<div class="customer_card">
  <div class="customer_card_logo" title="Changer de client"><span class="material-icons-outlined"> autorenew </span></div>
  <div class="customer_card_informations">
    <span class="customer_card_name">Company Name</span>
    <span class="customer_card_addresse">Adresse <br> ZIP CITY NAME</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.customer_card {
    background: green;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 20% 80%;
    gap: 0px 10px;
    justify-content: center;
    justify-items: stretch;
    align-items: center;
}

.customer_card_logo {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    background: grey;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.customer_card_logo > .material-icons-outlined {
    align-self: center;
    justify-self: center;
    font-size: 2rem;
    transition: all 0.4s;
}

.customer_card_logo:hover > .material-icons-outlined {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.customer_card_name {
    display: block;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.customer_card_addresse {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}

<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <head>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined|Material+Icons+Two+Tone|Material+Icons+Round|Material+Icons+Sharp" rel="stylesheet">

    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="customer_card">
        <div class="customer_card_logo" title="Changer de client"><span class="material-icons-outlined"> autorenew </span></div>
        <div class="customer_card_informations">
            <span class="customer_card_name">Company Name</span>
            <span class="customer_card_addresse">Adresse <br> ZIP CITY NAME</span>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

<!-- end snippet -->
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, when answering questions, please don't just dump a load of code in - please try to explain what you have changed and how it fixes the issue

Answer (score 0):

Using inline element span inside a div with display grid creates that gap. By adding width 100 percentage to your span will fix it.

Below you could find the code.

```css
    .customer_card{
        background: green;
        padding: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 20% 80%;
        gap: 0px 10px;
        justify-content: center;
        justify-items: stretch;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .customer_card_logo {
        display: flex;
        position: relative;
        justify-self: center;
        text-align: center;
        background: grey;
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .customer_card_logo > .material-icons-outlined {
        width: 100%;
        align-self: center;
        justify-self: center;
        font-size: 2rem;
        transition: all 0.4s;
    }
    .customer_card_logo:hover > .material-icons-outlined {
        transform: rotate(90deg);
    }

    .customer_card_name {
        display: block;
        font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 1.5rem;
    }

    .customer_card_addresse {
        font-size: 1.2rem;
    }
```

```html
        <head>
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined|Material+Icons+Two+Tone|Material+Icons+Round|Material+Icons+Sharp" rel="stylesheet">

        </head>
        
        <div class="customer_card">
            <div class="customer_card_logo" title="Changer de client"><span class="material-icons-outlined"> autorenew </span></div>
            <div class="customer_card_informations">
                <span class="customer_card_name">Company Name</span>
                <span class="customer_card_addresse">Adresse <br> ZIP CITY NAME</span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3b1kLzv2/5/